# Launching and sending data to a native android app from an adobe air app

Tags: android, air

I know its very simple to send data using intent in android.

But my problem is that I have an android app developed with adobe air, and I need to launch another native android app written with eclipse and java.

I hope someone can give me clue on how to launch another app and also send data across.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Java you can write an "AIR Native Extension" which gives you access to all the native classes, from there it should be fairly simple

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html